# Notify property changed in WCF service

Tags: wpf, wcf, inotifypropertychanged

I have a WPF application which calls WCF service methods through a Client which exposes these methods. Is there any way to bind my application to a property of the service, and to get notified when this property changes? I know INotifyPropertyChanged but I have some doubts about its efficiency in this case... Thanks

EDIT : Actually, all I want is my application to be notified of the changes that happen on the server side.

Comment: Please describe your doubts in more detail. Also: do you want to be notified of changes on the server?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of questsions here. You can bind your code to the client end of a WCF service and by using a partial class definition you can add an INotifyPropertyChanged interface to it so that it meets your design. But actually wiring up the mechanism for pushing updates from the server would be much harder.

In fact, Events will work over WCF, and reasonably performant i.e. you won't have the delay associated with polling. However I wouldn't try to squeeze your WCF code into fitting the INotifyPropertyChanged pattern. Instead use a more bespoke interface for the client/server comms and then expose the INotifyPropertyChanged back in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a delegate to your service, then call the service from your view model or code behind and reflect the changes with your properties that implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

In Service:

```
public delegate void ServcieUpdate(SomeDataType data);

public ServcieUpdate OnServcieUpdated { get; set; }
```

When data is updated:

```
if (OnServcieUpdated != null) OnServcieUpdated(data);
```

In view model:

```
private ServiceClient serviceClient = new ServiceClient();
private ObservableCollection<SomeDataType> data = new 
    ObservableCollection<SomeDataType>();

public YourViewModel()
{
    serviceClient.OnServiceUpdated += OnServcieUpdated;
}

public ObservableCollection<SomeDataType> Data
{
    get { return data; }
    set { data = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Data");
}

public void OnServcieUpdated(SomeDataType data)
{
    Data = data;
}
```

Please take a look at the [Delegates (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) page on MSDN in you are unfamiliar with using `delegate` objects.

Comment: This doesn't solve the getting updated when there are changes on the server side

Comment: You *might* want to take another look... that is *exactly* what it solves (through the use of the `ServcieUpdate` `delegate`).

Comment: How is this callback going to be marshaled over WCF?

Comment: This is in the service client so whenever data comes through, the `delegate` can be called.

Comment: How is the data going to be pushed from the server to the client?

Comment: Ahhh... I've just seen the user's edit. In which case, you have a good point. Thanks for your persistence.

Comment: No problem, it is always hard to keep track of moving targets. Especially when you don't know they're moving  :)